# Maximum cost without cycles

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph with positive edge costs, choose a subset of edges such that there are no cycles and the sum of the cost is maximal.
The input consists of several graphs, each defined with number of vertices n, number of edges m, and m triples x,y,c to indicate an edge between x and y of cost c. The vertices are numbered from 0 to n - 1. It is assumed that 1 ≤ n ≤ 104, 0 ≤ m ≤ 5 n, and 1 ≤ c ≤ 105. there may be more than one edge between two vertices, and even edges with x = y.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using P = pair<int,int>;
using VE = vector<int>;
using VP = vector<P>;
using VVE = vector<VP>;

int n,m;
VVE G;
VE cost; 
VE vist; 
VE pare; 

int maxim(int x){
   if(cost[x] != -1) return cost[x];
   cost[x] = 0; 
   for(P y: G[x]){
      if(cost[x] <= y.second + maxim(y.first)){
        cost[x] = y.second + maxim(y.first);
      }
   }
 return cost[x];
}

int main() {
  while(cin >> n >> m){
     G = VVE(n);
     cost = VE(n,-1);
     pare = VE(n,-1);
     for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
         int x,y,c; cin >> x >> y >> c; 
         G[x].push_back(P(y,c));
         G[y].push_back(P(x,c));
     }
     int mx = -1; 
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
         if(mx <= maxim(i)){
             mx = maxim(i);
         }
     }
     cout << mx << endl; 
  }
}
```

This is my code and I don't know how to solve the problem. I would appreciate help. As you can see the graph is read as a vector of vectors. In which each pair indicates that node x goes to node y with cost c.

Comment: That sounds like a maximum spanning tree.

Comment: You will get a better response if you tag your questions accurately.  Add the programming language tag :  this seems to be C++.  This problem is graph-theory, but not graph.

Comment: @beaker You are correct

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter pointed out, this is the maximum spanning tree problem (which is the same as the minimum spanning tree problem, just negate the costs). That problem can be solved with the greedy algorithm. Initially place every node into a heap on its own. Then in a loop consider the edges in decreasing cost order. If the two endpoints of the considered edge are in the same heap, discard the edge. Otherwise select it and merge the heaps. When you have only one heap left, you can stop, and the selected edges form your solution.